# In SSH Local Port Forwarding what DNS server is used to resolve the host (not the ssh gateway)?

Tags: ssh, dns, ssh-tunneling

In local port forwarding, what DNS server resolves the name of `internal_db.local`?

Would that be the internal SSH server's DNS? (that's what I would think)

Or is it the external DNS server that assigns the `sshgateway.com` its address?

For example:

```
ssh -L 4000:internal_db.local:3306 user@ssh.sshgateway.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete sequence of a port forwarding in ssh is
`-L [<local_ip>:]<local_port>:<remote_ip>:<remote_port>`
whereby the local_ip can be omitted.

The `<local_ip>` (or the DNS name) will be resolved from the local host and the `<remote_ip>` (or DNS name) by the remote host (in your case that is sshgateway.com).

Edit based on your comment:
Correct me if I don't get it.
Your environment looks like this:

```
host_1  ->   host_2   ->   host_3
your_PC -> sshgateway -> internal_db.local
```

and you want to connect from host_1 to a database located on host_3.
With your suggested local port forwarding you forward port 4000 of host_1 through host_2 to port 3306 of host_3.
For that, your connection will be tunneled through ssh from host_1 to host_2 and then send as normal ip-packets from host_2 to host_3, as if host_2 would connect to the database.
Therefore host_2 (sshgateway.com) has to resolve the ip address of host_3 (internal_db.local) with his DNS server.
Hope that clears your question.

Comment: I think you accidentally a word.

Comment: @leeand00 I just took back your editing as local host was meant to refer to the local machine and not to localhost as in 127.0.0.1

Comment: @TrippKinetics I'm not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: "The (or the DNS name)" ??

Comment: You got it.....

Comment: @bey0nd Okay you're not understanding the command I don't think (I could be wrong); but the `remote_ip` is behind the `ssh_gateway`; the second part of my command says "login to user@ssh.sshgateway.com" but forward the ports from `internal_db.local` to my localhost, so I can connect to the database through SSH using Local Port Forwarding.

Comment: @bey0nd  Yes that's what I was attempting to achieve when I wondered about adding an SSL certificate (actually I got a webserver connected to a database) but then I realized that without a FQDN it's pretty hard to use an SSL certificate...so I wondered how it was in this situation that DNS factors into it; which server is called etc...will it use `/etc/hosts` to override the primary DNS etc...yeah, so thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Port forwarding in SSH involves a local IP, a local port, a remote IP, a remote port, and a destination.  As in:

```
ssh -L $LOCAL_IP:$LOCAL_PORT:$REMOTE_IP:$REMOTE_PORT $DESTINATION
```

In this example, DNS names for `$LOCAL_IP` and `$DESTINATION` are resolved by the environment in which the `ssh` command runs.  DNS names for `$REMOTE_IP` are resolved by the environment at `$DESTINATION`.